# The greatest common divisor of multiple numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, combinatorial-number-theory

What is the cardinality of the following set

$\{{\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_d): \text{each } x_i\in \{ 1,\dots,n \},\text{ and } \gcd({\bf x})=1\}$,

where $\gcd({\bf x})$ is the greatest common divisor of $x_1,\ldots,x_d$.

A condition we have is that we know the amount of prime numbers in $\{ 1,\dots,n \}$, which is denoted as $n_p$.

I think we first need to find those with $x_1<\dots<x_d$, then handle those with $x_i=x_j$, and then easily for non-monotone cases. Note that ${\bf x}$ is a row vector, so the order of $x_i$ matters.

I hope I could obtain an explicit formula for the set's cardinality by using $n,d,n_p$.

Comment: Please show us that you have made at least some attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Does your notation $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ mean a row vector?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, Yes, it is a row vector.

Comment: I have an answer, if summation is allowed. But you must first show some work of your own so this question can be reopened.

Comment: @bburGsamohT: I think we first need to get those with $x_1<\dots<x_d$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I do not understand your meaning "if summation is allowed". I hope I could obtain an explicit formula for the cardinality.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I have updated the question. Hope it could be reopened. I do not think to obtain an explicit formula for the cardnality is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a simple closed formula, but here is one that uses summation.

If we ignore the requirement on the greatest common divisor, we have $d$ successive choices to make, each choice with $n$ possibilities. This would mean $n^d$ cardinality for your set.

But we must remove the elements with $\gcd>1$. For those vectors whose $\gcd$ is $2$, we can get each of them by taking a vector with choices from $\{1,2,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\}$ (where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function) and multiplying each vector member by $2$. So we need to remove $\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor^d$ set elements. For $\gcd=3$ we remove $\lfloor\frac n3\rfloor^d$ set elements.

For $\gcd=4$, those were included in the ones for $\gcd=2$, so we can ignore them. For $\gcd=6$, we have included them once and removed them twice, for $2$ and for $3$. So we need to add back $\left\lfloor\frac n6\right\rfloor^d$ set elements.

You probably see the idea. For $k$ prime or the product of an odd number of distinct primes, we subtract those set elements, for $k$ one or the product of an even number of distinct primes we add them, and for $k$ divisible by the square of a prime we ignore them. The [Möbius mu function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), $\mu(k)$, does just what we want. So your desired cardinality is

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)\left\lfloor\frac nk\right\rfloor^d$$

There probably is a way to abbreviate that, but I don't know it. Note that I did not use or need $n_p$, though perhaps that may be usable in an abbreviation. I checked my formula with several examples in Microsoft Excel, and they all check.

Comment: if $a_d(n) = \sum_k \mu_k \lfloor n/k \rfloor^d$ then $$F_d(s) = \sum_n a_d(n) n^{-s} = -\sum_{m=0}^{d-1} C_d^m (-1)^{d-m} \frac{\zeta(s-m)}{s \zeta(s)}$$

Comment: @user1952009: That looks and is impressive, but since it is still a summation does that improve on my answer? Do we assume that $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function and $C_d^m$ are binomial coefficients?

Comment: yes, I looked at its Dirichlet series to see if $a_d(n)$ could be expressed from other number-theoritic functions, but these $\frac{\zeta(s-m)}{\zeta(s)}$ quotients seem to have no specific definition.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Your answer is good enough. I do not need the formula must be with $n_p$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_k = 1$ for a $k \leqslant d$. Then we have $\gcd (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_d) = 1$ as mentioned. Having satisfied that condition, we have $d - 1$ elements to choose from the remaining $n - 1$ numbers, which are done in ${{n - 1} \choose {d - 1}}$ ways, so there are ${{n - 1} \choose {d - 1}}$ elements in your set.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. First, the order of $x_i$ matters. Second, (3,7,7,7,7) has gcd=1 but it is not in the set when n=7 and d=5.

Comment: @Harry: Why isn't it in the set? It matches your requirements for the set. Do you mean it is not in the set described by Nima Bavari?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, Yes, your understanding is correct. I meant (3,7,7,7,7) is in the set I defined but not in the one described by Nima Bavari

Answer (score 0):

How many sequences of length $d$ and values in $\{1, \ldots , n\}$ are there?

This is the number of variations: $n^d$.

For given prime number $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
How many sequences of length $d$ and values in $\{a | a \in \{1, \ldots , n\} ,
 p | a\}$ values are divi^dsible by $p$) are there (?

There are $\lfloor{n/p}\rfloor^d$ these sequences. We define $f(p) := \lfloor{n/p}\rfloor^d$.

Let $A_n :=  \{1, \ldots , n\} \cap \mathbb{P} $.
$A_n = \{ p_1, \ldots, p_s \} $ where $p_s$ are primes.

For calculating result from qiestion, we apply inclusion-exclusion principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).
From the total number of sequences: $n^d$ we must substract number of all sequences of elements divisibled by prime numbers: $f(p_1)+ \ldots + f(p_s)$. But we have got substracted sequences of elements divisibled by pairs: $(p_i, p_j), i \neq j$ twice. Hence we must add $\sum _{1\leq i<j \leq n}f(p_ip_j)$. Etc.

We get result:
$n^d    - \sum _{1\leq i \leq n}f(p_i) + \sum _{1\leq i<j \leq n}f(p_ip_j) 
- \sum _{1\leq i<j<k \leq n}f(p_ip_jp_k)+ \ldots$

finally:
$$n^d - \sum_{t=1}^{n} (-1)^t \sum _{1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots <i_t \leq n}f(p_{i_1}p_{i_2}\ldots p_{i_t}).
$$